# CeRapiInit or CeRapiInitEx?

Tags: windows-mobile, activesync, rapi

CeRapiInit() does not return until a device is connected and initialization is complete (synchronous).
CeRapiInitEx() does, but requires a callback event handler (asynchronous). All I want is a "connecting to device" dialog with a cancel button. Which is the better approach? Any code sample out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :-)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831883